# Selenium, creating simple dialog box while running chrome tests using Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, dialog, webdriver

Learning `Java` & `Selenium`. I researched dialog box and came up with this:

```
<Code to run some selenium test>

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Completed Boundaries Test.  Press Ok for next test.");

<Code to run some other selenium test>
```

Idea is to have such dialog statement between tests so that user can validate the run, instead of relying on sleep and visually looking at the result--which is prone to error.

I couldn't get it to work.  I don't know what to pass for frame.
Here is my chrome driver and first test:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Screen Maximize Completed.  Press ok for next test.");

System.out.println("County Lines Checkbox Test, Default is checked, let's uncheck");
WebElement chkCounties = driver.findElement(By.id("chkCounties"));
chkCounties.click();
```

Comment: Why would you interrupt the execution of an automated test to get a person to press ok?  The objective of automation is to replace a person having to do the tedious tests so that they can focus on innovative exploratory testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the object of `JFrame` and pass it as below :-

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

// now create the JFrame object
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(false);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Screen Maximize Completed.  Press ok for next test.");

System.out.println("County Lines Checkbox Test, Default is checked, let's uncheck");
WebElement chkCounties = driver.findElement(By.id("chkCounties"));
chkCounties.click();
```

Hope it helps..:)